# Intervalos FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Olá

Estou enfrentando um problema com a biblioteca do Fullcalendar.
Estou fazendo um projeto na qual utilizo a agenda para organizar minhas aulas.

Inicio às 08h00 e tenho 40 minutos de aula.
Paro meio dia, e retorno 13h30.

O problema é que ao retornar, o intervalo aplicado de 40 minutos continuou no horário do meio dia, e gostaria que ao voltar 13h30, os 40 minutos de cada aula fossem contados a partir das 13h30.

(Na lógica ele continuar somando os 40 minutos, indo das 12h00 às 12h40, 12h40 às 13h20, 13h20 às 14h00 ....)
Na teoria, gostaria que fosse:
08:00 às 08:40
08:40 às 09:20
09:20 às 10:00
10:00 às 10:40
10:40 às 11:20
11:20 às 12:00
**12:00 às 13:30**
13:30 às 14:10
14:10 às 14:50
e continua de 40 em 40 minutos....

Gostaria também que na grid da calendário, o box respeitasse a linha limite do compromisso, conforme linha vermelha apresentada na imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém já passou pro esse problema?
Poderia me ajudar por gentileza \o/